# Переменная типа [пользовательский класс]?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, классы

Не могу представить в чем суть `Title title` в приложенном коде. Это переменная? Это объект? Это ссылка на объект? Если у этого есть название, то был бы рад узнать его дабы почитать об этом подробнее на просторах интернета.

```
namespace Task_3
{
    class Book
    {
        readonly Title title;


        public Book(string title)
        {
            this.title = new Title(title);
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            title.Show();
        }
    }
}



    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Book book = new Book("C#");           

            book.Show();

            // Delay.
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Оформите код текстом.

Comment: это поле класса.

Comment: То, что это поле класса ясно. Изучаю Троелсена и, дойдя до полиморфизма, так и не нашел ничего подобного. Т.е. я могу представить переменную типа string, но это с одной стороны похоже на переменную типа Title(что вообще сложно представить) либо на объект класса Title. Нашел данный пример в готовом решении практического задания курса ITVDN после изучения инкапсуляции.

Comment: `title` - это ссылка на экземпляр класса `Title`, которая является полем класса `Book` (причем полем только для чтения)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос вы случайно дали в заголовке вопроса. Любой класс в C# является ссылочным типом данных, обратное также верно - любой ссылочный тип данных является классом.

Отличие между типами и классами существует, и заключается в том, что типы есть у переменных, полей и прочих элементов языка, а классы - у объектов. Но это отличие непринципиальное, просто так исторически сложилась терминология.

Формально `title` в вашем коде переменной не является, `title` - это поле. Но неформально поля можно называть переменными, они очень похожи.

Объектом `title` формально не является; в поле находится ссылка на объект класса `Title`. Но неформально можно сказать и "объект `title`", подразумевая тот объект куда это поле указывает.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь эта строчка `Title title` обозначает что создается объект ссылочного типа(типа **`Title`**) с именем **`title`**. То есть где-то создан класс Title, который описывает заголовок у книги. Это не стандартный класс .NET, это самописный класс.

### Пример

```
public class Title
{
    string _name;
    public Title(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: @VladD подскажите пожалуйста, как вы форматировали мою строку в код? Пытаюсь уже несколько дней разобраться не понимаю, что делать

Comment: Можно либо вставить по 4 пробела перед каждой строкой, либо выделить код и нажать кнопку `{}` сверху (в режиме редактирования ответа).

Comment: [Справка по Markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @VladD Спасибо!

Comment: @РамильМухаметшин: Пожалуйста!